# Angular.js model defined in JavaScript, one property needs to be evaluated as a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've defined my model in the JS like so:

```
$scope.requirement = {
  id: function() {
    if($scope.dada || $scope.lala) {
      return $scope.dada
    }

    return $scope.haha
  }
}
```

The variables are nonsense but pretend they're defined (they are in my circumstance, this is just an example).

And then in the HTML with Angular directives I have an input like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="requirement.id" placeholder="ID">
```

The value returned from the function is not the value of `requirement.id`.  How can I pass a function like above but have Angular.js evaluate the function and use the returned value?

Edit:

I tried this which didn't work:

```
$scope.requirement = {
  id: null
}

if($scope.dada || $scope.lala) {
  $scope.requirement.id = $scope.haha;
}
```

When I run a `console.log(requirement)` the value is changed however it doesn't represent the new value in the view.  The input in the view still shows `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing two way binding, you need to define `id` as a getter/setter function that has one argument.  So when a value is passed it acts as a setter, updating the model.  Otherwise it just gets the current value based on your logic.

```
$scope.requirement = {
  id: function(newId) {
    if (arguments.length) {
       $scope.dada = newId;
    }
    return ($scope.dada || $scope.lala) ? $scope.dada : $scope.haha;
  }
}
```

You have to update your input element and add ng-model-options attribute.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="requirement.id" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

If you're just talking about one way binding, then you don't need to use the getter/setter or ng-model.

```
<input type="text" value="{{requirement.id()}}" readonly />
```

Comment: The id isn't passed from the view.  My goal is to have the function evaluated and the view represent the returned value of the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  So do you just need one way binding?  In that case you don't need ng-model.  Remove that attribute and add the following `value="{{requirement.id()}}"`.

Comment: Where does `newId` come from?

Comment: newId is the value the user enters when typing into the textbox.

Comment: Let me explain the use case and maybe that'll help.  I'm defining the model in the JavaScript and then using it in the HTML.  The default value for `id` prior to passing a function to it was just `null`.  I want the value of `id` to be null conditionally, hence the function.  `id` should be `null` unless a condition is true, I want it to be a different value and have that new value be represented in the view.

Comment: If the user can update the id (two-way binding) then user the first example as a guideline.  If the user can't (one-way binding) then keep your function the same and use the second example.  Whatever the logic is - it isn't important.

Comment: I tried defining `id` as `null` and then outside of the object I manipulated the `requirement` object conditionally but it didn't update in the view.  Check the edit in the OP.

Comment: Here's the exact snippet from my code: `<select class="form-control" ng-model="requirement.sap.id" ng-options="option.name for option in case.cps track by option.id">
                     </select>` And then the JS in the edit.  When I console.log `requirement.sap.id` it's been updated to the value it should be, but it's not represented in the view, the HTML select

Comment: Problem was due to select `ng-options` syntax.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model is two-way binding and the way you defined it requirement.id returns a function object (it does not execute the function), but even more, it will overwrite that object when people fill in your input field, because you told Angular to put the value of the input box into the requirement.id variable. If you only need to get the value, use {{requirement.id()}} or even more readable {{requirement.getId()}}.

If you do really need two-way binding with a function go for Daniel's solution.